# is there a limit to the number of partials a rails view can send to the client?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ok so on my show view I have made a dashboard with a side nav that toggles different partials.

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#chartsP, #tablesP, #formsP").hide();
   });
   function dash(){
     $("#chartsP, #tablesP, #formsP").hide();
     $("#dashboardP").show();
   };
   function chart(){
     $("#dashboardP, #tablesP, #formsP").hide();  
     $("#chartsP").show();
   };
   function table(){
     $("#dashboardP, #chartsP, #formsP").hide();
     $("#tablesP").show();
   };
   function form(){
     $("#dashboardP, #chartsP, #tablesP").hide();
     $("#formsP").show();
   };
 </script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <nav id="c_nav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  </nav>
  <div id="admin_sidenav" class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav in" id="side-menu">
      <li>
        <a onclick="dash()">
        <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i>
         Dashboard
       </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a onclick="chart()">
        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i>
         Charts
        </a>              
      </li>
      <li>
         <a onclick="table()">
        <i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i>
         Tables
       </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a onclick="form()">
          <i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Forms</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a >
          <i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> UI Elements<span class="fa arrow"></span>
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
<div id="dashboard_content_area">
  <div id="dashboardP"><%= render 'instructors/partials/dashboard' %></div>
  <div id="tablesP"><%= render 'instructors/partials/tables' %></div>
  <div id="formsP"><%= render 'instructors/partials/courseforms' %></div>
  <div id="chartsP"><%= render 'instructors/partials/charts' %></div>

</div>
```

what I have noticed is that only 3 of the partials end up being sent to the client, for example if I were to look at the elements in chrome dev tools I would see the first 3 there, but "chartsP" would be absent, yet if i switch the order it always seems like the 4th partial gets discarded.

Comment: No, there is no limit. Could it be that your javascript is hiding the div which contains the partial you are looking for?

Comment: No because if it was hidden it would still appear in the HTML in chromes dev tools. Additionally the it doesn't matter which partial I put as the last one just never gets loaded.